# Image not displaying on my JLabel

Tags: java

Called this method to my main form class it would select the file but wouldnt display image..
Snippet

p

```
ublic class imageSending {

 public  static File setpix(File k) throws IOException {


   //     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 


         JFileChooser choose=new JFileChooser();
        choose.setDialogTitle("Browse Image");
        choose.setFileSelectionMode(2);
        int a=choose.showOpenDialog(null);
        if ( a==0){
        File file=new File(choose.getSelectedFile().getPath());

            BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(file);


            ImageIcon o = new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(300, 300, 300));
    }return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in that code that would display an image. If you have other image displaying code, please show it, and please explain your question in greater detail.

Comment: And also, 1) the JFileChooser, `getSelectedFile()` returns a File -- why are you making it more convoluted by getting the path and then getting a File with the Path? 2) What is `k` that you're returning? 3) You're creating a BufferedImage and then with this creating an ImageIcon, but doing nothing with the Icon that you've created -- why?

Comment: Ah, I see that `k` is the parameter -- why is the method even taking a parameter and then simply returning it? It's as if all the code in the method body is just busy work that the program is going to ignore, and so this is getting more confusing -- please help us out here by explaining what this code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is your method above in a nutshell

```
public  static File setpix(File k) throws IOException {
    // do lots of busy work that accomplishes nothing
    // and then return k:
    return k;
}
```

That's it. If you want to actually display an image in your GUI you should instead:

1. Get the File obtained from the JFileChooser. Just call `getSelectedFile()` no need to convert it to a String and then get a File
2. Get your BufferedImage from the file and convert it to an ImageIcon
3. **Have the method return the ImageIcon**
4. Somewhere else, call the method and put the Icon into your JLabel via `setIcon(...)`.

For example (code not tested)

```
public Icon getIcon() throws IOException {
    JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser();
    choose.setDialogTitle("Browse Image");
    // choose.setFileSelectionMode(2); // no "Magic" numbers
    choose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES); // Better
    int a = choose.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (a == 0) {
        File file = choose.getSelectedFile();
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(file);
        Icon o = new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(300, 300, 300));
        return o;
    } else {
        // throw an exception here
        // or return null if that's what the program expects
        // or return some "default" icon
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
Icon icon = getIcon();
myLabel.setIcon(icon);

// or
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
```